# Need help in solving a quasilinear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Setting 
$$ u(x,y) = e^{ax+\beta y} v(x,y) $$ 
bring the equation to an canonical form
$$\ аu_{xx} + 4au_{xy} + au_{yy} + bu_{x} + cu_{y} + u = 0 $$

Comment: Have you done something such as taking derivatives?

Comment: yes, I solved this, with the help of linear conversion of variables,
but I can't bring it to canonical look with this replacement

Comment: You said "solving" in the title of this thread but then in the thread itself you seem to be asking how to go from the given function to the differential equation.  If that is what you were asking then start by taking the derivatives of u and put them into the given equation.

Comment: some misunderstanding might occur, I need to bring this equation of hyperbolic type to an canonical look using already defined replacement

Comment: about "starting with the adoption of derivatives and putting them in a given equation" - already tried, then everything starts interesting, using this method with a replacement, I do not get right result after substitution to bring it to the canonical form

Comment: Oh, my mistake, I misunderstood the first question,
I take all the necessary steps, and after that I have some problems when substituting the results of the replacement

Comment: so as not to appear unfounded, that's what I substitute in the initial equation
[link](https://prnt.sc/hkkkae)